# How to list provided libraries and their versions in Glassfish 3?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish-3, dependency-management

I'm failing to list Java libraries that Glassfish 3.1.2.2 provides for applications run in domain. What I want is listing of libraries and their versions, so that I can configure `provided` scope for those libraries (that I use) in Maven POM.

I've tried:

- Checking the libraries through filesystem under `GLASSFISH_HOME/modules` but the filenames don't have version numbers
- `asadmin list-libraries` command, but it only lists libraries that are bundled inside domain
- `pkg` tool, but it doesn't provide comprehensive enough listing (it abstracts libraries' details behind alternative names and versions).
- Adding Glassfish as "Server" for the project in Eclipse, but it doesn't tell library versions either, and the selection of libraries it offers might not actually reflect reality. This is mostly gut feeling.
- Checking the READMEs as in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/downloads/glassfish-312-3rdparty-readme-1521433.html but it contains also non-Java libraries and I don't think the file is meant for what I'm doing.

How can I list names and versions of those libraries that are provided by Glassfish for the (web) applications deployed in a Glassfish domain?

Comment: Why would you want to *add* the GlassFish libraries in your POM? Add your functional requirement, otherwise this is a silly question. The GlassFish libraries are specific for the Java EE implementation, it means, you can't run a Web Application w/o them, but you don't need them in your POM.

Comment: See the comment that I added to m3th0dman's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in adding your libraries that Glassfish uses in your Maven dependencies; so long as you have the API to them Glassfish comes with the implementation when your application is deployed.

However you can use the whole Glassfish server as a library in your application without the need of installing Glassfish and deploying your application. You can see more details about [Embedded Glassfish here](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/).

Comment: There are libraries, that are not part of Java EE spec. For example slf4j and logback are there, among others. Also, different implementations have different flavors and I need this code during development (=compilation). What you mean here with embedded Glassfish is that I should add that as a maven dependency, with `provided` scope?

Comment: With the embedded version you can use basicaly all the functionality of Glassfish is provided directly to your application from a library; yes you should add it as a dependency in your pom.xml. There is also a Maven plugin for this.

Comment: Tried adding `org.glassfish.main.extras:embedded:3.1.2.2` as a dependency to POM. Unfortunately that artifact doesn't come with any dependencies so your suggested solution doesn't work.

Comment: Also tried `org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:3.1.2.2` but it just lists optional zip-package as dependencies.

Comment: Those are practically the same, I just used different version. If you take a look at the POM you can see that it doesn't actually list Java dependencies: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.pom